# Fan not working at all

Tags: 10.04, ati

I have a Dell Studio 15 laptop.

It has an ATI mobility radeon graphics card using the opensource drivers
It is running ubuntu 10.04

It runs for a while (10-20 minutes) and then turns off.

acpi -t  shows the cpu temperature slowly rising until it turns off.

acpi -c  shows two cooling devices both set to 0 (off)

I'm worried that this is damaging my laptop.

Is their a way to force the fan to turn on any other way to solve this problem.

I logged into the Bios to see if there was any way to force the fan on, while it was in the bios screen the computer turned off. Does this suggest its not a ubuntu problem?

I tried running ubuntu 10.10 from a live cd, but still no fan, I turned it off when the temperature got to 95 degrees.

Installed windows vista on it and still no fan. I'm guessing it's a hardware problem at this point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the BIOS as suggested under the dell support website. (you can only do this from windows).

Randomly turning off was listed as a common problem. And updating the bios was the suggested solution.

My fan now works under both windows and ubuntu. And so I can happily say this was not a ubuntu problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have a good look in the kernel log as sometimes you can see recommendations for turning things on or off.
Just as an example I had a line that said  Local APIC disabled by BIOS it then gave a reccomendation to use lapic, after adding this to grub, it now reads Local APIC disabled by BIOS -- reenabling. Found and enabled local APIC!

Answer (score 1):

From your description you have a hardware problem, not a software problem. You should report this to your laptop's manufacturer.